# Beamer button hyperlink to another frame - issue with full screen

Tags: beamer, pdf, hyperlink

I'm having an issue with the position of the frame to which the beamer button redirects when using full screen.

In the example below, when I click on the button in the first frame, it redirects to the third frame in the right way, but when I click on the "back" button to return to the first frame, the result is that I'm in the middle of the first frame, between the first and the second ones. I recommend compiling the code and checking this directly in the pdf, it will be clearer.

When presenting the pdf in the full screen mode, I would like the button to always redirect to the full frame which it is pointing to. How can I do it?

PS: In my original document this problem is happening in the first case too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\label{frame1}

This is the frame in which there is a button \hyperlink{frame3}{\beamerbutton{link}}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\label{frame2}

This is just a random frame

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
\label{frame3}

This is the frame where the button redirects to \hyperlink{frame1}{\beamerbutton{back}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about the `\hypertarget` or `\hyperref` commands? See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks. Do they fix the issue?

Comment: I see no problem, tested on windows 10 in adobe reader and sumatra.

Comment: @pluton using ```\hypertarget``` and ```\hyperref``` generates the same result.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right, it works fine with Adobe Reader. The problem happens only with browsers like Chrome, Edge or Brave